# Zero length ROW (ROW()) misbehaviour

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use PostgreSQL 10.3.

The following statements give the same result: `true`;

```
SELECT ROW() IS NULL;
SELECT ROW() IS NOT NULL;
```

and the next one

```
SELECT ROW() = ROW();
```

gives:

```
"ERROR: cannot compare rows of zero length"
```

So, if a row is of **zero length**, then is it **unknown**, **not unknown** or **both**?

And, how can I check if a **row** is of zero length or not?

Tia

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html

> If the expression is row-valued, then IS NULL is true when the row
>   expression itself is null or when all the row's fields are null, while
>   IS NOT NULL is true when the row expression itself is non-null and all
>   the row's fields are non-null. Because of this behavior, IS NULL and
>   IS NOT NULL do not always return inverse results for row-valued
>   expressions

regarding the way to tell the row attributes count. I'm not sure how to do it neat, but you can think of many monkey ways, eg:

```
t=# SELECT count(1) from (select json_object_keys(row_to_json(ROW(1,2,3)))) a;
 count
-------
     3
(1 row)

t=# SELECT count(1) from (select json_object_keys(row_to_json(ROW()))) a;
 count
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

Comment: In this case the row is neither `NULL` nor `NOT NULL`. It is of zero-length. In addition: `SELECT ROW() IS DISTINCT FROM NULL;`  is `true` and `SELECT ROW() IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL;`  is `false` which both are consistent and make more sense. Thanks for the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not allow comparison of rows of zero length.

To check the size of a row, try [pg_column_size](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-admin.html):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (a TEXT, b TEXT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('foo','bar'),('foo','bar2');

SELECT pg_column_size(a)+pg_column_size(b) FROM t;
```

To check if it is **zero**:

```
SELECT pg_column_size(ROW())-24=0
```

Comment: I have not found any reference in the official documentation about the comparison of rows of zero length. Is there any other source? Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: hey @SONewbiee. I am really not aware of this feature.. when I need such functionality, I always use this workaround I posted in my answer.